# Mod rewrite question (really a regex problem)

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

Ive started out with the most basic rewrite there is, take any request and give it to my index page:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Im trying to change it now so lets say i have a directory called special, I actually want to be able to go to http://example.com/special and access whatever files are in there.

I tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^special/.*$ index.php [L, QSA]
```

but it didnt work.

Answer (score 3):

Try either this:

```
RewriteRule !^special/ index.php [L]
```

Or this:

```
RewriteRule ^special/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to apply to any directory, try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUESTFILENAME}!-d 
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```